# Как вывести последние 10 записей в библиотеке redbeanphp

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Надо вывести последние n ое количество заисей для такого формата записи

```
$sm  = R::find('messages', 'dialog = ?', array($_GET['set']));
```

Просто sql не предлагайте

Comment: Если find возвращает массив: `$sm = array_slice($sm, -$n);`
где `$n` - количество элементов

Comment: Чтоб не засорять форум, можно ещё один вопрос?... Надо вывести 10 записей начиная с 10 ой

Comment: `array_slice($sm, 10, 10);`

Comment: у вас 1 решение на всё :D

Comment: пасиб...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sm = array_slice($sm, -$n);
```

где $n - количество элементов